# Check if group of checkboxes are checked but not disabled

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

This code:

```
if ($('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').is(':checked') && $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':disabled')) {
        $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').prop('checked', false);
} else if ($('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':checked') && $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':disabled')) {
        $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Seems to ignore the second part of the if clause;  If a checkbox is checked I want it to be ignored.

I have tried it also doing `is(':disabled)` with a preceding `!`, also tried for a `boolean` `!(element).prop('disabled');` -- all to the same effect.

The code above is definitely called because ALL checkboxes will toggle checked state -- the question revolves around the inability of ignoring the disabled checkboxes.

Is my logic wrong here?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: What part is missing?  I will verify that some checkboxes have  `disabled='disabled'` when I inspect element.

Comment: Depends on what your expectations are. I suspect you have expectations for `is()` that aren't correct

Comment: `.is(':checked')` will return true even only one checkbox in matched set is checked

Comment: @A.Wolff  So should I just do an `each` loop then

Comment: @KickingLettuce you should compare length: `$('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').length === $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]:checked').length`

Comment: @KickingLettuce you still haven't provided expected results. Faulty code isn't a substitute for an explanation of what it should do

Comment: I am sorry, I thought it is explained above.  All checkboxes toggle when this is called.  Regardless if it is disabled or not.  I want only NON-disabled checkboxes to toggle.  Anyhow, I figured it out with an answer below.  I used an `each` loop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work a little better:

```
$('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').each(function(elm) {

    var $elm = $(elm);

    if($elm.is(':checked') && !$elm.is(':disabled')) {
         $elm.removeProp('checked');
    }
    else if(!$elm.is(':checked') && !$elm.is(':disabled')) {
         $elm.prop('checked', 'checked');
    }

});
```

As A. Wolff says above, `.is(':checked')` will return true even only one checkbox in matched set is checked. You need to loop through the elements using `each`.

Comment: Ok, this worked best.  I simplified it a bit and used `$(this)` instead of declaring the elm.

Comment: Never use `removeProp()` for setting boolean attribute to falsy or you won't be able to set it to true again. `removeProp()` will delete the property. Use `.prop('checked', false);` instead

Comment: @KickingLettuce its best to cache the jQuery element for performance reasons (but if you've just changed the `var $elm = $(elm);` to `var $elm = $(this);`, that will still be fine)

Comment: @rwacarter oh good point, thanks.  Also I did this instead,  `$(this).prop('checked', '');` instead of `removeProp`.

Answer (score 1):

The .not() in jQuery is only a filter that reduces the current set of elements. It does not return a boolean if it is disabled.

Comment: And BTW even jq empty object is truly

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!obj.is(':checked'))`, example:

```
if ($('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').is(':checked') && $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':disabled')) {
     $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').prop('checked', false);
} else if (!$('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').is(':checked') && $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':disabled')) {
     $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Another example, if you want to reach unchecked checkboxes after you check checked, just separate you logic, example:

```
if ($('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').is(':checked')) {
    if ($('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':disabled')) {
         $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').prop('checked', false);
    } 
} else {
    if ($('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').not(':disabled')) {
         $('[id*="cat' + cat_id + '_sk"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
    }   
}
```

Comment: @charlietfl that was just an example.

Comment: @KickingLettuce In case it didn't than you're missing something. Provide HTML part. One more guess - try switching `else if` to just `if`.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Another example with separated statements.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/133/

```
if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('disabled') != 'disabled')
```

the above line of code is the logic that says if this checkbox is checked and not disabled

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('disabled'));
        if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
            $(this).after('Checked and not disabled');
        }
    });
});

<input type="checkbox" class="check" checked disabled/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" checked disabled/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" checked /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" disabled /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /><br/>
```

hope this helps